# What design pattern is proper for this situation?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm learning design patterns and I am confused because I don't know what pattern is best for this situation:

I have String and this String may be various. It may be "123abc", "abc123", "abcdfe" or "123456" and only like those string's.

```
public void doSomething(String variousString) {
    StringType type = checkType(variousString);
    if(type==StringType.Mixed) doMixedAction();
    if(type==StringType.OnlyLetters) doOnlyLetterAction();
    if(type==StringType.OnlyDigits) doOnlyDigitsAction();
}
```

Firstly I thought about **Strategy** pattern but I think that It doesn't match here. Now I think that **Chain of Responsibility** is matching here very well.

What is the best pattern for remove if statements in this situation? What are your opinions?

Comment: Yes the chain of responsibilities looks like the best one to use here...

Comment: Certain problems do not call for design patterns. Sometimes a Banana is Just a Banana.

Comment: Why not use a switch statement?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes but It's only simple example. What if It will be more complex? E.g. this String will be Iban number and you will be needing to decide how to send money transfer and method of sending moneys will be depending on first 8 numbers of Iban?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this scenario. A if-else tree (maybe abstracted) combined with different predicates that check for the various "types of strings" should suffice. I don't know if there's a "pattern" that describes this.

Comment: It looks like a regular expression problem to me

Comment: Don't force design patterns all over your code. Sometimes a problem can take a solution much simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

Not the classic design pattern, but simple Map can be used as well

```
public class Main {
    private final Map<StringType, Runnable> bindings = new HashMap<>();

    public Main() {
        bindings.put(StringType.Mixed, () -> doMixedAction());
        bindings.put(StringType.OnlyLetters, () -> doOnlyLetterAction());
        bindings.put(StringType.OnlyDigits, () -> doOnlyDigitsAction());
    }

    public void doSomething(String variousString) {
        bindings.getOrDefault(checkType(variousString), () -> {}).run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you show with `StringType` can likely be considered a Type System. Essentially the relevant patterns here are likely to be a simple 'switch', Strategy Pattern, or Visitor.

What patterns/ implementation should be chosen depend largely on the scope & variability of Actions and Types.

Some questions to consider:

- are the Actions few in number & reused as infrastructure throughout the application, or will the application create many arbitrary actions?
- are the Types fixed?
- would it be useful for Action implementations to be able to delegate to each other, eg. to build complex behaviors out of simpler ones?

Now to the patterns.

### In business logic, with a simple switch

- implement `MyProcess.doAction()` with a switch to choose the implementation appropriately.
- suitable when the Actions are many/ or not known to the Type System, but the Types are fairly well fixed.

### In the Type System, with a simple switch

- implement `StringType.doAction()` with a switch to choose the implementation appropriately.
- suitable when the number of "Types" is modest & known in advance to the type system.

### Strategy Pattern in the Type System

- subtype or parameterize instances of `StringType` to implement the `doAction()` method appropriately.
- suitable when the number of "Actions" needed is modest & known in advance to the type system.
- Strategy can also allow 'Chain of Responsibility'; this arises when Strategies delegate.

### Visitor Pattern, despatched from the Type System

- define a StringVisitor (oh my, a meaningful name would make this so much easier).
- which implements visitMixed(), visitOnlyLetters(), visitOnlyDigits() methods.
- the StringValue or some helper can then despatch, according to type, onto an arbitrary visitor.

To be honest the question and example given are poor & lacking in meaning, for meaningful design answers to be given -- but the following should give you some food for thought.

I'd definitely suggest you try and make a meaningful domain model out of these things (IBAN Codes, if that's what they are). You will need to consider what your concrete types & actions are, and the relative dynamicity/ fixedness of these, to get a proper design.