# Using Command Pattern to send and receive commands over serial

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, command-pattern

I am working with a desktop app that should send and receive commands via serial with a firmware being programmed by my coworker.

We have devised a protocol where command types are represented by ASCII letters, each command type might contain a payload (which is arbitrary between command types, but fixed for each type), and commands are wrapped in square brackets. For example, we have the following commmands:

- `[S1234]` -> Sent vrom the PC to the device to store a new serial number, or from the device to the PC to inform the current serial number (sort of a getter/setter command);
- `[R]` - Sent from the PC to the device to ask for a "get serial" command;
- `[A12]` - Sent from the the device to the PC to inform a new ADC reading;
- `[B]` - Sent from PC to device to ask for a battery charge;
- `[B89] - Sent from device to PC to inform battery charge;
- Etc.

So I have a class that receives and parses the incoming bytes, and each time a command is successfully parsed, an event is raised, with the following tentative signature:

```
internal event EventHandler<SerialCommand> CommandReceived;
```

Where `SerialCommand` would have different subtypes: BatteryCommand, AdcCommand, SerialCommand, and others. Each command type is to be associated with its respective "char code".

My question is: how should the client code use this? For example, the current implementation for when I receive a command has a switch/case with hard-coded char literals, which I find very fragile and ugly:

```
    void CommandReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialCommand command)
    {
        switch (command.Code)
        {
            case 'A':
                int value= Convert.ToInt32(command.Value);
                _frameStreamer.AddFrame(new Frame<int>(new[] { value}));
                break;
            case 'B':
                BatteryLevel= (int)command.Value;
                break;
            case 'D':
                DoSomething((byte)command.Value);
                break;
            case 'S':
                SerialNumber = (int)command.Value;
                break;
        }           
    }
```

Currently, these "char codes" are spread around a bunch of classes, and if I ever need to change a given code, I would need to look around for every occurence (shotgun surgery anti-pattern).

What I need to do are two things:

- Encapsulate char codes inside the very commands only, instead of client code;
- Polymorphically execute actions at the client (`CommandReceived` event consumer) preferrably without the switch/case statement.

Comment: maybe simple map can help you, check the last answer in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035984/what-design-pattern-is-proper-for-this-situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseCommand
{
    //Code not needed at all, because logic encapsulated into command
    //public char Code { get; set; }         
    public abstract void Action(IClient client);
}

public abstract class BaseCommand<T> : BaseCommand
{
    public T value { get; set; }
}

public class CommandA : BaseCommand<int>
{            
    public override void Action(IClient client)
    {        
        client.someInt = value * 2;
    }
}

public class CommandB : BaseCommand<string>
{
    public override void Action(IClient client)
    {
        client.someString = value.Trim();
    }
}

public interface IClient
{
    void CommandReceivedHandler(object sender, BaseCommand command);    
    int someInt { get; set; }
    string someString { get; set; }
}

public class Client : IClient
{
    public void CommandReceivedHandler(object sender, BaseCommand command)
    {
        command.Action(this);
    }

    public int someInt { get; set; }
    public string someString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I liked the way you provide the client instance to the command instance, instead of the opposite which is what I have been trying. I believe this is the way the Command Pattern is intended to be used - either by passing a  client instance or a client metod to the command.

Comment: Actually I think I'll go with a variant where I pass the client via constructor, not via action call. Either way, the collaborations are equivalent. Thanks!